# Posting data from table

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am generating a table at runtime, now i want to POST all these data so i can insert it into database.

I want to post all name and quantities into my Codeigniter controller.

[image]

Comment: And where is your code

Comment: Okay, good luck with that :) - On a more serious note, please give [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good read :)

Comment: what have you tried so far. Just a refreshment google.com is a good starting point. Search for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `jQuery`

```
$.(document).ready(function(){
  $.post('YourController/methodName/paraMeter').done(function(data){
     alert('Success !');
  })
})
```

**SOLUTION TEXT**

I am generating a table at runtime,

> now i want to POST all these data [-- ON READY -- POST Required DATA --]

so i can

> insert it into database. [ Controller -> Model ]

I want to post

> all name and quantities into my Codeigniter controller. [ -- Fetch by `$('#id').html()` or `.value()` Anything you are okay with and Send to Controller via `.post` method as your data in PARAMETERS ]

Thanks and Regards